# Want it to output sentence after loop but it won't compile

Tags: java, compiler-errors, initialization

I have to calculate the highest and lowest grades for the 50 grades inputted and also say who had the perspective grade. Here is the problem code:

```
max=-999;
min=1000;
while(inFile.hasNext())
{
    name = inFile.next();
    grade = inFile.nextInt();
    inFile.nextInt();

    if(grade > max)
    {
        max = grade;
        maxName = name;
    }

    if(grade < min)
    {
        min = grade;
        minName = name;
    }

    System.out.println(minName + " has the lowest grade of " + min);
    System.out.println(maxName + " has the highest grade of " + max);

}
```

I tried putting `System.out.println(minName + " has the lowest grade of " + min);`after my `while` `loop` but it gave me the error:

```
H:\Java\Lab6.java:202: error: variable maxName might not have been initialized
    System.out.println(maxName + " has the highest grade of " + max);
                       ^
```

But when I put the `.println` in the `if statements` like so:

```
if(grade > max)
{
    max = grade;
    maxName = name;
    System.out.println(maxName + " has the highest grade of " + max);
}

if(grade < min)
{
    min = grade;
    minName = name;
    System.out.println(minName + " has the lowest grade of " + min);
}
```

it gives me this output:

```
Robert has the highest grade of 70
Robert has the lowest grade of 70
Joel has the lowest grade of 64
Alice has the highest grade of 98
Larry has the lowest grade of 42
Christine has the lowest grade of 20
Alex has the lowest grade of 10
Mathew has the highest grade of 100
```

All I want is the last two because those are right.

Comment: It may be that you declared "minName" and "maxName" but haven't initialized it. If so, there might be a chance that you won't go into any of if clauses and you wan't initialize it later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just as you initialize min and max to fake values before the loop, you should also initialize minName and maxName to something:

```
String minName = null;
String maxName = null;
```

Otherwise, since the compiler can't guarantee that the loop executes at least once, it can't guarantee that these variables have been initialized to some value (as the error message indicates).

BTW, your code should handle this case some way: if there is 0 entry in inFile, you should probably detect it (the minName would still be null, for example), and you could write an error message.